# How to assign factor levels by the weight of strings in a vector?

Tags: r, r-factor

I want to assign factor levels depending on the string weight. Normally R appears to assign factor levels alphabetically:

```
set.seed(54)

x <- sample(1:10, 5000, replace = TRUE)
x <- "levels<-"(as.factor(x), LETTERS[1:10])

> summary(x)
  A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J 
524 508 519 489 477 496 507 526 473 481
```

I can reorder the factor levels and reassign them like this:

```
l <- data.frame(x=summary(x), old.levels=names(summary(x)), 
                        row.names = NULL)

l <- transform(l[order(summary(x)), ],
               new.levels=LETTERS[1:10])

levels(x) <- l[order(l$old.levels), 3]

> summary(x)
  I   G   H   D   B   E   F   J   A   C 
524 508 519 489 477 496 507 526 473 481
```

But by this I haven't changed the factor values:

```
> summary(as.factor(as.numeric(x)))
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
524 508 519 489 477 496 507 526 473 481
```

How can I get smartly what I want?

Comment: when you are reordering too, the numeric encoding starts from 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default behaviour for `factor` is indeed to order the levels and then assign
labels.

```r
set.seed(54)

x <- sample(letters[1:10], 5000, replace = TRUE)

f1 <- factor(x, labels = LETTERS[1:10])
f2 <- factor(x, levels = sort(unique(x)), LETTERS[1:10])

summary(f1)
#>   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J 
#> 524 508 519 489 477 496 507 526 473 481
identical(f1, f2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

If you just want the labels assigned in frequency order, you can do that by
reordering the labels when creating the factor:

```r
f3 <- factor(x, levels = sort(unique(x)), LETTERS[1:10][order(table(x))])
summary(f3)
#>   I   E   J   D   F   G   B   C   A   H 
#> 524 508 519 489 477 496 507 526 473 481
```

If you want the labels in frequency order and the levels sorted alphabetically, order the *levels* during factor creation instead:

```r
f4 <- factor(x, levels = sort(unique(x))[order(table(x))], LETTERS[1:10])
summary(f4)
#>   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J 
#> 473 477 481 489 496 507 508 519 524 526
```

Created on 2018-03-16 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).